# Change the look of android options menu

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I would like to create android options menu (left button on android device) looking like this one:

[image: screen1]

but using onPrepareOptionsMenu creates the menu which looks like this one:

[image: screen2]

Could you please point me how to change the look of the menu? Is there anything I can set in menu XML to change it's look or maybe I should use: onPrepareContextMenu?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: The top one is from Android 4+ and the bottom one is from Android 2.3 and below. They are the standard menus for those Andriod versions.

Comment: Not really. I made both screenshots on ICS 4. First one is from Gmail application. So it's absolutely doable :)

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855148/how-to-create-bottom-menu-like-gmail-android

Comment: @ariefbayu thanks, but your link is about the "action bar menu" and not "options button menu".

Comment: what is your targetSdk version in your manifest?

Comment: @Ran: I don't set targetSdk version in my manifest yet. Only minimum as 8.

Comment: I think that's the problem. When the targetSdk is 14 and above than Android will automatically show the new menu layout.

Comment: @Ran: But I want menu from top picture for all versions ( I don't want new menus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

attribute to the `<activity>` tag in project's AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="YourActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
          >
```