# how to create option menu with click on textview in android

Tags: android, onclick, textview, touch

i am trying to build the android application story book.In this application when user touch the screen of story i want option menu to come out from bottum .i tried to find it out on google but didnt get any reasonable answer.please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855148/how-to-create-bottom-menu-like-gmail-android

Answer (score 0):

just call

```
activity.openOptionsMenu();
```